# How to verify linear functional form in a MLRM?

Tags: multiple-regression, assumptions, gretl

I'm performing a Linear regression but I don't know how to verify that the coefficients are linear (Performing with Gretl software) could you guys help me to find a way to verify this?

Comment: Welcome to CV. On the whole, this site is not intended to be a resource for software-specific questions. However, your question does have a strong statistical base that is independent of Gretl. So, responses should be forthcoming.

Answer (score 0):

In gretl's GUI (graphical interface), you get a new window with your estimated model. There you will find a menu "Tests" (or the translated version of that), and in that menu two entries "non-linearity (squares)" and "non-linearity (logs)" which will perform some tests that should be relevant, if I understand you correctly.

In the CLI (command-line or script interface) of gretl you would do "modtest --squares" or "modtest --logs" to do the same thing, after having estimated a model with ols.

Apart from the gretl specifics, these generic tests run auxiliary regressions with additional terms, namely squared and log'ed terms as the names suggest, and test for exclusion of these additional terms.